# An expression that adds little information

Tags: vocabulary

There is a family of expressions called oxymorons which contain contradicting meanings. What about expressions that add little meaning like "fatally injured" or "the evening sunset"? What are these expressions called?

Comment: It's called, freedom of speech

Comment: How does “fatally” not add meaning to “injured”?

Comment: If it's in the context of an accident, the expression doesn't add anything to the fact that a person was instantly killed. On the other hand, saying that a person succombed to their injuries adds the information that they were still alive shortly afterwards.

Comment: I think "fatally killed" is a better example, that would be better reduced to "killed". If they weren't killed, then of course they were just "injured".

Comment: "fatally injured" invariably means someone didn't die *at the time of the injury*. They died later, probably either in hospital or in an ambulance on the way there, despite best medical efforts. It's not at all a "superfluous" pairing of words.

Comment: Are you certain of that FumbleFingers? If so, should the expression be used post mortem?

Comment: I'd say that some time gap is implied, but 'fatally wounded' is certainly not tautologous. I've added a different example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are known as **tautologies** or **tautologous expressions**.

Some examples from the [Guardian Style Guide](http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide/):

> **Aum Shinrikyo**
>   means Supreme Truth sect, but note that the "aum"
>   means sect, so to talk about the "Aum sect" or "Aum cult" is
>   tautologous
>
> **affidavit**
>   a written declaration made on oath, so "sworn
>   affidavit" is tautologous.
>
> **Eid al-Adha**
>   (Festival of Sacrifice) Muslim festival laid down in
>   Islamic law, celebrates the end of the hajj. Note that eid means
>   festival, so it is tautologous to describe it as the “Eid festival
>
> **gambit**
>   an opening strategy that involves some sacrifice or concession;
>   so to talk of an opening gambit is tautologous — an opening ploy might
>   be better
>
> **regalia**
>   plural, of royalty; “royal regalia” is tautologous

As a side note, tautologies are often found in [place names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tautological_place_names), my favourite is The La Brea Tar Pits, meaning The The Tar Tar Pits.

Comment: I'll accept your answer. Do you happen to know if there is a difference between tautology, pleonasm and redudancy? Or are they synonymous?

Comment: They can usually be used synonymously in this context, but of course there are subtle differences: http://www.fun-with-words.com/redundancies.html Tautology is also a term used in logic, and redundancies can apply to lost jobs and having extra backup computer systems in case one stops working (such as in the shuttle).

Answer (score 4):

I've found the word I was looking for. It's pleonasm:

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pleonasm

> pleonasm (countable and uncountable; plural pleonasms) (uncountable,
>   rhetoric) Redundancy in wording.  [quotations ▼] (countable) A phrase
>   involving pleonasm, that is, a phrase in which one or more words are
>   redundant as their meaning is expressed elsewhere in the phrase. "The
>   two of them are both the same" is a pleonasm (as the word "both" is
>   redundant), as is "killed dead".

Some better examples:

- "Could you repeat that again?"
- "The crowd was vociferating loudly."

In the same genre there is also redundancies and [tautologies](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tautology).

Comment: Yes, I would probably go for "pleonasm" in your case-- there's not much in it, but possibly "pleonasm" is more common if you mean more of a linguistic phenomenon (e.g. a redundant phrase that is commonly used as you have), whereas a "tautology" is more of a redundancy of logic or redundancy used as a rhetorical device. But as I say, I don't think there's so much in it either.