# Using an adjective to describe something that is already intended

Tags: meaning, nouns, adjectives

Is there a word that describes the case of using an adjective to describe a noun that already suggests as much?

**Examples**

> - the *pretty model* won all of the awards
> - the *smart genius* answered every question
> - the *dangerous monster* ate the man
> - the *fast jet*
> - the *floating buoy*

Some of these examples might not be the best, but I hope they give the right idea.  I know they are superfluous, but I'm not trying to define the adjectives themselves, but the act of using them.

Comment: They're all just *appropriate* adjectives. There's an element of [tautology](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tautology) in *smart genius*, but not really in any of the others. The [overuse of adjectives](http://www.clarityworksonline.com/the-practice/articles/working-with-words/working-with-adverbs-and-adjectives-1) is a *"common mistake for new [creative] writers"*, but apart from calling it *flowery* or similar, I don't know any dedicated grammatical term for this.

Comment: Redundancy, perhaps?  I gave the example, "the professional MLB player" which is super redundant.

Comment: Similar to "eponymous".

Comment: @Jacob: *Most* people, *most* of the time, would assume that the words being bandied about here - *tautology, superfluous, redundant,* etc., imply negative criticism. But in fact all your examples just show how people actually use English (both spoken and written), so it would be just as correct to call them ***normal***. You could perhaps say the adjectives are being used to *amplify* or *emphasise* an implicit meaning.

Comment: 'Pleonasm' is the fancy word for redundant terns.

Comment: @Mitch: Pleonasm seems to work for me.  Wikipedia gives the example "a burning fire" for it, which is intended and thus what I'm looking for.  If you give an answer, I'll accept it.  at FumbleFingers: Thank you for the detailed responses! :)

Comment: Probably a dupe of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40419/an-expression-that-adds-little-information/40421#40421

Comment: I searched but didn't find that question, since his question is asked much differently from mine.  It might prove beneficial to have both questions asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would normally call an expression with a *redundant* adjective that served only to express a *tautology*, a *pleonasm*. Pleonasms are not always a bad thing, as they can add clarity or emphasis.

Note though:

A *model* is anyone whose body is used aesthetically, as a photographic or artistic subject, or as a background for clothes, demonstrably, or otherwise, and not necessarily pretty.

A djinn or spirit—for which *genius* is a synonym—may not be smart, and some quite stupid genii figure in some stories.

That monsters by several definitions, need not be dangerous.

That *fast* is relative, and some jets are much slower than others.

That some buoys can sink when damaged.

Hence these are not true pleonasms.

Comment: I presume that these sentences would be used in context, and with the context, one would assume that the model is beautiful, or that the monster is going to eat someone since this particular one has huge teeth.  So these phrases may not be true pleonasms, but it was the word I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You could describe them as *redundant* if they're not actually needed, but sometimes redundancy and repetition can be useful to emphasise an important point and paint a fuller picture.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty model is not necessarily redundant. Just because she is a model does not make her "pretty". She could be a sub-par model who is the daughter of the boss. A smart genius could mean someone who is thin and intelligent. A monster might be psychologically evil but not dangerous. A fast jet describes one in the air and not on the ground. And a floating buoy is one in the water and not in the fish house. Adjectives all have their wondrous place next the the noun.

Comment: All due respect, but this was already addressed earlier, both your part, and my response.  See the accepted answer!  You are right though, adjectives do have a wondrous place.